# How to nest package.json variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have two scripts `prod` and `build` as given below and I'm accessing them both as [package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) for creating another script `build_prod` as follows:

```
"prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production BABEL_ENV=production",
"build": "webpack",
"build_prod": "npm run $npm_package_scripts_prod $npm_package_scripts_build"
```

Running `npm run build_prod` from the terminal works perfectly, as expected. But if I try to nest `build_prod` in another script, it gives an error - missing script.
ie, After changing build_prod 
from `npm run $npm_package_scripts_prod $npm_package_scripts_build` 
to `$npm_package_scripts_prod $npm_package_scripts_build` 
 and adding script: `"build_final": "npm run $npm_package_scripts_build_prod --config prod.config.js"`
and running `npm run build_final` from terminal.

I searched for some time about nested package.json vars but could not find any information, even in the [official documentation of package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars).
Do npm support nested variables ? If so, what is the right way of creating nesting scripts ?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use _package.json vars_ to reference a script from another script. instead of referencing the script names? For instance:  `"build_prod": "npm run prod && npm run build"`

Comment: @RobC The above command `"build_prod": "npm run prod && npm run build"` will not set the environment variables `NODE_ENV=production and BABEL_ENV=production"` for the second command `build`. The environment variables have to be set again separately for `build` command. I am trying to reuse the code here, using the nested concatenation of the package.json vars.